# Mapping from $\{1,\ldots,n!\}$ to the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there an easy known bijective mapping formula between the set $\{1,\ldots,n!\}$ and the symmetric group $S_n$? I want to pick a number $k \in \{1,\ldots ,n!\}$ and assign a unique permutation of $(1,\ldots, n)$ to it.

Numbering the transpositions generating $S_n$ doesn't help, since they can occur multiple times and don't commute. Maybe the permutation matrices (in every column and row exactly one 1 and 0 elsewhere) could give a hint, but I don't see the solution.

Context: I want to simulate a certain probability distribution on the symmetric group. It's easy to pick random integer numbers. So easy mapping a random number to a permutation is left.

Comment: There is not only one map (even bijection) between these sets. Are you looking for a map with some special properties?

Comment: @user44400: there is a clear bijection.

Comment: @Horst: I guess you want a open map, I think finding recursive formula is easier, is it also ok  for you ?

Comment: @mesel: I did not meant to say that there is no such bijection. I mean that there might be more than one (just bijections between sets without any further structure).

Comment: @mesel: A recursive formula is OK. What do you mean with "open map"? There is no topology involved. Rather measurability, but that's trivial between these finite sets.

Comment: @user44400: True, I don't need the group structure for my mapping. I don't need the isomorphism. Especially if it's computationally costly to implement.

Comment: @user44400: there are exactly $(n!)!$ such bijections.

Comment: This is discussed at length in *Higher-Order Perl*, [section 4.3.1](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/04Iterators.pdf), pp. 128–135.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is an easy and well known such bijection, although as happens so often (that I don't understand why people don't just get into the habit) it becomes easier if one starts counting at $0$, so that one is looking for a bijection between permutations of the set $[n]=\{\,i\in\Bbb Z \mid 0\leq i<n\,\}$ and the (similar) set $[n!]$. Using the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system), a number of the latter set is represented as an $n$-tuple $[d_n,\ldots,d_1]$ with $d_i\in[i]$ (as is conventional the least significant digit it as the right), and this sequence can be mapped to a permutation using the [Lehmer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system). Both conversions are straightforward and easily computed in both directions, and combining them numbers the permutations in *lexicographic* ordering. Nonetheless the one between a permutation and its Lehmer code not quite as easily computed as one should like (it is not even $O(n\lg n)$ using any obvious data structure), which makes use of this mapping loose out against direct methods when it comes to efficient *enumeration* of permutations in lexicographic order. However, it would still be a method of choice if you want to store information about permutations in a tight linear array, and need to be able to look up the information associated to a given permutation rapidly.

Comment: Yes I support zero as the first number.

Answer (score 4):

See [Generating all permutations](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc2b.pdf) by Donald E. Knuth.

Comment: Apart from a link to this bootlegged copy, you might want to mention that this has since been published in volume 4A of The Art of Computer Programming.

Answer (score 2):

Since we know that $S_{n}$ has $n!$ elements, you are really asking for a "natural" ordering on the the permutations in $S_{n}.$ Possibly the simplest way to do this is lexicographic ordering: given distinct permutations $\sigma$ and $\tau,$ set  $\sigma > \tau$ if for some $i \leq n,$ we have $\sigma (i) > \tau(i)$ but $\sigma(j) = \tau(j)$ whenever $j <i.$ This lists the elements of $S_{n}$ in a strictly increasing order, with the identity permutation being the "smallest". The $i$-th permutation in the list should be assigned the number $i.$

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of simplicity, I am providing a mapping from $\{0 \cdots (n! - 1)\}$ to the set of permutations of $\{0, 1, \cdots, (n-1)\}$. Please offset by 1 where required.

First of all, note that $n! = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i.i! + 1$ (can be easily proved by induction).

So for any number k in the range you provided, k - 1 can be written in the form

$k - 1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_{i}i!$, where in each case $a_i$ is an integer from $[0, i]$.

Associate with k the permutation $p_{1}p_2p_3\cdots p_{n-1}p_n$ where $p_1$ = $a_1$, $p_2$ is the $a_2$th element in $\{0, 1, \ldots, {p_1-1}, {p_1+1}, \ldots (n-1)\}$, and so on.

You can easily see that a unique permutation is associated with each $k$ here.

EDIT: I went ahead and wrote the code. See this:

`#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
def get_perm(n, k):
  """get permutation corressponding to random number. k < n!"""
  used = [False] * n
  fact_arr = [0] * n
  this_fact = 1
  perm = []
  for i in range(n):
    this_fact *= (i + 1)
    fact_arr[i] = this_fact
  k1 = k
  for i in range(n - 1):
    this_fact = fact_arr[n - 2 - i]
    p = k1 / this_fact
    k1 = k1 % this_fact
    p1 = p
    idx = 0
    while p1 > 0 or used[idx]:
      if not used[idx]:
        p1 -= 1
      idx += 1
    perm.append(idx + 1)
    used[idx] = True
  for i in range(n):
    if not used[i]:
      perm.append(i + 1)
      break
  return perm
def main():
  perm = get_perm(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]) - 1)
  print perm
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()`

Now if I run, eg.

for i in \$(seq 1 6); do ./permutations.py 3 \$i; done

The output is:

`[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to define such a bijection by recursion on $n$:

- If $n=1$, use the only possible bijection.
- Let's say you've done it for $n$ and you want to move on to $n+1$.  You've listed all $n!$ permutations of the first $n$ letters of the alphabet.  Let's say $n=1\text{ gazillion}$ and the first $n$ letters of the alphabet are $A,\ldots, K$, and the $(n+1)$th letter is $L$. Write the first permutation on your list as the first $n$ letters in some order, thus: $$\bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet$$ and then make a list of $n+1$ new permutations by putting $L$ in each of the $n+1$ positions: $$\begin{array}{c} \bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet L \\ \bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet\bullet L \bullet \\ \bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet L\bullet\bullet \\ \bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots L\bullet\bullet\bullet \\  \vdots \\  \vdots \\ \bullet\bullet\bullet L\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet \\ \bullet\bullet L\bullet\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet \\ \bullet L\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet \\ L\bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet \end{array}$$ Then do this with $\bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet$ as the second permutation of the $n$ letters (except this time let $L$ move from left to right), then with $\bullet\bullet\bullet\cdots\bullet\bullet\bullet$ as the third (with $L$ going from right to left), and so on.  *This method always goes from one permutation to the next by interchanging two adjacent letters.*

  Concrete example: $$\begin{array}{l} \begin{array}{c} A \end{array} \\[12pt]  \begin{array}{c} AB \\ BA \end{array} \\[12pt] \begin{array}{c} ABC \\ ACB \\ CAB \\ CBA \\ BCA \\ BAC \end{array} \\[12pt] \begin{array}{c} ABC\,D \\ AB\,D\,C \\ A\,D\,BC \\ D\,ABC \\[6pt] D\,ACB \\ A\,D\,CB \\ AC\,D\,B \\ ACB\,D \\[6pt] CAB\,D \\ CA\,D\,B \\ C\,D\,AB \\ D\,CAB \\[6pt] D\,CBA \\ C\,D\,BA \\ CB\,D\,A \\ CBA\,D \\[6pt] BCA\,D \\ BC\,D\,A \\ B\,D\,AC \\ D\,BAC \\[6pt] D\,BAC \\ B\,D\,AC \\ BA\,D\,C \\ BAC\,D \end{array} \end{array}$$ I think this recursive method may bear a standard name, but I don't remember it.

There is also something called a de Bruijn sequence.